# Compare files then overwrite original with new file

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for a vb code to do the following:

1. Compare **File A** with **File B**

**File A** (source located in drive L:\source) contains the following:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
1A1B
```

**File B** (user located in local drive D:\user) contains the following:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
111
222
333
```

2. Overwrite **File A** (user) with **File B** (Source)
   so that **File A** (final user file) will be as follows:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
1A1B
111
222
333
```

Note:

**Source File A:**

`AAA` is the same line as in File B `aaa`.

`BBB` is the same line as in File B `bbb`.

`CCC` is the same line as in File B `ccc`.

`DDD` doesn't exist in File B.

`1A1B` doesn't exist in File B.

**User File B**:

`aaa` is the same line as File A `AAA`, lower case was used to differentiate it with the Source file.

`bbb` is the same line as File A `BBB`, lower case was used to differentiate it with the Source file.

`ccc` is the same line as File A `CCC`, lower case was used to differentiate it with the Source file.

`111` is a user line

`222` is a user line

`333` is a user line

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to use this service.  At a bare minimum, you need to show us what code you have tried and I don't see a single line.  NOBODY is going to write this program for you.  LOTS OF PEOPLE are more than happy to help you get there by writing the program yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for letting me know where to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code I'm not going to write the whole thing from scratch, but I'm happy to share and explain my approach and help if you run into trouble with the actual code.

**Step 1**

I would create 4 total lists (collections):

- 1 for each original string value in file A: **CollectionA**
- 1 for each original string value in file B: **CollectionB**
- 1 for each `.ToLower` value of each string in file A: **CollectionALowers**
- 1 for your output values: **CollectionOutput**

Example: `Dim CollectionA As List(Of String)`

**Step 2**

Read each line of file A, but when you process each line you will do 3 things with it:

1. Copy the value into CollectionA
2. Copy the value into CollectionOutput
3. Copy the `.ToLower` version of the value into CollectionALowers

**Step 3**

Read each line of file B into CollectionB.

**Step 4**

Use a for-each loop to check each value in Collection B to see if its in CollectionA by checking the collection's .IndexOf method, except when making the check, you are taking the `.ToLower` of the B item and checking for its index value in the ToLower version of A's collection.  If its index is > -1 that means it's already there so you don't need to add it to the output collection, but if the index is -1 then it isn't in A's lowercase collection so you add the original (non-ToLower) version of the B string to the output collection.

```
For Each item as String in CollectionB
  if CollectionALowers.IndexOf(item.tolower) = -1 Then
    CollectionOutput.Add(item)
  end if
Next
```

**Step 5**

Write the contents of CollectionOutput back to file A, overwriting the original file contents.

**Thoughts**

Having said all of the above, I'm not sure that you actually need a separate CollectionOutput.  Instead, you could add the item to CollectionA.  Just from a resource perspective, that would use less memory and is more efficient.  However, I've found that my own programs tend to grow and become more complex over time, and that keeping things in distinctly different buckets often comes in handy down the road as your program evolves.

Have a go at it and once you have some code to share, post it if you need help.